# jqueryui autocomplete doesn't show dropdown for same input

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete

I found that when you enter the same term into the jQuery autocomplete the second time the dropdown doesn't appear. Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you using [jQuery-ui's autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) or some other autocomplete plugin? (the one from jQuery-ui shouldn't have that issue) Do you have some code to show? Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: @darkajax Yes, I'm using jqueryui autocomplete and apparently when your source is custom (in my case I make an ajax call) than it will not call the source function again if the user enters the previous term.

Comment: @darkajax You can see the problem going to http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ then type java (now you can see the pop up with two options) press ESC key, then SHIFT+HOME and retype java, now you can't see the popup

Answer (score 0):

IF you write again then it will show the dropdown but if you select from form auto suggest then it will not as because it will see no diference between previous and current.

Comment: Please see my comment regarding this on top.

Answer (score 0):

After the autocomplete configuration, I'm trying to use something like

```
$("#myTextBox").autcomplete(...);

$("#myTextBox").keypress(
    function () {
        var term = $("#myTextBox").val();
        if (term && term.length >= $("#myTextBox").autocomplete("option", "minLength"))
            $("#myTextBox").autocomplete('search');
    });
```

But is working a bit slow (multiple calls to search), maybe I should implement a time delay, but I think is too much work for a simple workaround and my lack of jquery knowledge

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery UI 1.8.19 is fixed http://blog.jqueryui.com/2012/04/jquery-ui-1-8-19/ but I can't see the description in the changelog so maybe was fixed earlier